# Datatable calendar on VisualBasic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a request to show a grid similar to a calendar showing on columns the day and on row months.

Something like this

```
Month   |Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|...|Thu|
January |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11|...................| 31|
Febrary |   |   |   |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|...........................| 29|
...
December| 30| 31|   |   |   |   |  1|  2|  3|  4|............................
```

Is there a way to do this, considering that The Start day of the year must be the real day name, not a constant and this must be generated dynamically

I try this but my idea goes off!

```
Private Sub GenerateCalendar(ByVal year As Integer)
        Dim colsCount As Integer = 3
        If Bisiesto(año) Then
            colsCount = colsCount + 366
        Else
            colsCount = colsCount + 365
        End If
        Dim dtCalendar As New DataTable
        dtCalendar.Columns.Add("Mes")
        Dim dayMonthYear As Date = New Date(year , 1, 1)
        'Showing the distribution of the first month
        While dayMonthYear.Year = año And dayMonthYear.Month = 1
            Dim dtColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn()
            dtColumn.ColumnName = WeekdayName(Weekday(dayMonthYear)) & dayMonthYear.Day & dayMonthYear.Month
            dtColumn.Caption = WeekdayName(Weekday(dayMonthYear))
            dtCalendar.Columns.Add(dtColumn)
            dayMonthYear = diaMesAño.AddDays(1)
        End While
        Dim row As DataRow = dtCalendario.NewRow()
        'Here I need to distribute the days on its column day
        dtCalendario.Rows.Add(row)

        wdgCalendario.DataSource = dtCalendar
        wdgCalendario.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Public Function LeapYear(ByVal year As Integer)
        Dim isLeapYear As Boolean = False
        If year Mod 4 = 0 Then
            If (year Mod 100 = 0) And Not (year Mod 400 = 0) Then
                isLeapYear = False
            Else
                isLeapYear = True
            End If
        Else
            isLeapYear = False
        End If
        Return isLeapYear 
    End Function
```

Comment: Suggestion: you can use `DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)` to determine if it is a leap year or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note**: You cannot have duplicate column names in the DataTable, so i have appended the weekday with the number of week in month. But see it for yourself:

```
Private Function GetCalendarTable(year As Int32) As DataTable
    Dim curCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
    Dim firstYearDate = New Date(year, 1, 1)
    Dim currentDate = firstYearDate
    Dim tblCalendar = New DataTable
    tblCalendar.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("MonthName"))

    Dim maxDiff = 0
    For m = 1 To 12
        'find max difference between first year's weekday and month's first weekday
        'if the latter is earlier in the week, it is considered to be in the next week
        Dim monthFirstWeekDay = New Date(year, m, 1).DayOfWeek
        Dim diff = (7 + (monthFirstWeekDay - firstYearDate.DayOfWeek)) Mod 7
        If diff > maxDiff Then
            maxDiff = diff
        End If
    Next

    Dim weekDayNum = curCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, 1) + maxDiff
    ' Create DataColumns with weekday as ColumnsName
    For wd = 1 To weekDayNum
        Dim weekday = currentDate.ToString("ddd")
        Dim weekInMonth = (From col In tblCalendar.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)()
                          Where col.ColumnName Like String.Format("{0} W#", weekday)).Count + 1
        Dim columnName = String.Format("{0} W{1}", weekday, weekInMonth)
        tblCalendar.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(columnName))
        currentDate = currentDate.AddDays(1)
    Next

    ' Create the DataRows(every month)
    For m = 1 To 12
        Dim daysInMonth = curCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, m)
        Dim firstMonthDate = New Date(year, m, 1)
        Dim daysBefore = (7 + (firstMonthDate.DayOfWeek - firstYearDate.DayOfWeek)) Mod 7
        Dim daysBehind = tblCalendar.Columns.Count - (daysBefore + daysInMonth) - 1

        Dim monthDays = From d In Enumerable.Range(1, daysInMonth)
                        Select New With {.Day = d.ToString}
        Dim emptyDaysBefore = From d In Enumerable.Range(1, daysBefore)
                        Select New With {.Day = ""}
        Dim emptyDaysAfter = From d In Enumerable.Range(1, daysBehind)
                        Select New With {.Day = ""}

        Dim monthName = curCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(m)
        ' piece together parts
        Dim allFields = ({New With {.Day = monthName}}.
                       Union(emptyDaysBefore).
                       Union(monthDays).
                       Union(emptyDaysAfter).
                       Select(Function(d) d.Day)).ToArray
        tblCalendar.Rows.Add(allFields)
    Next

    Return tblCalendar
End Function
```

Comment: How do you add a first column to put the name of the month?

Comment: @Juan: Updated my answer. Maybe there is a simpler way to put the monthname to the first column but it should work.

Comment: @Juan: Wow, your calendar is more challenging than i thought ;) Updated the complete method. It was caused by the calculation of the difference between two weekdays, so when first weekday of year is a friday and a month's first weekday is a monday i cannot subract both because the latter must be in the next week.

Comment: The last code is not working, when the begining date of the month starts passing monday, the calendar doesn't show correctly

Comment: @Juan: Which year does not work for example and what means  _doesn't show correctly_? My sample page with a GridView works fine for years between 2010 and 2013. Have you copied the whole method because i've changed several things?

Comment: 2012 , 2017 shows correctly, but the others not. The vew appears something like this 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 8 9 ....

Comment: Is there a way to show you hole code and screen? by email maybe

Comment: I'm afraid not, you might want to add a screenshot to your question and add all related code there(you could delete it later when it works). But all i can tell you is that i don't see this behaviour, tested from 2010-2020. No repeating numbers and always starting from 1. So there must be a difference between your code and mine. You haven't answered my last question, have you updated your complete method with mine(also the parameter year)?

Comment: I have copied, i edited the post with an image displaying year 2013

Comment: @Juan: You should also use a link to a fullsize image, because SO shrinks images. As you can see from my linked screenshot(answer edited), i don't have this issue with above code.

Comment: This is the result I get when i select 2013 https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=2F430EFF41A684C0&id=2F430EFF41A684C0%21119

Comment: @Juan: There is no added value in this link since it was already obvious from the image in your question that something goes wrong. But you have not yet added the source code which is causing this issue since my code is working fine(as you can see).

Comment: @Juan: So you are using the same code to create the DataTable. But there must be a difference. I've changed my CultureInfo to `es-Pe`(Peru, like you) and it's still working fine. See my updated link to a screenshot in my answer. When are you binding the DataTable to the GridView? Can you show also this code.

Comment: I will try with a simple gridview

Comment: You are right, the problem is not the algorithm, is the control. I changed the webdatagrid to a simple grid view and works fine! Thanks.